# How to not display certain index in an Array without filter in Vue3?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

In vue2 if you wanted to not display a certain index in an array you could do something like:

```
this.tasks = this.tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== 1)
```

Where it would be used  show all values in the 'tasks' array except for task that has an id=1.

Now in vue3 using  you would have tasks as a ref value: `const tasks = ref([])`

How would you do the vue2 equivalent in vue3?

Answer (score 0):

Similar, for [ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) You use property `value`, try with :

```
tasks.value = tasks.value.filter((task) => task.id !== 1)
```